# Sense 5 mods on other devices

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, nexus-4, htc-sense

Is there any method to replicate the interfaces as in HTC Sense 5 on other android devices ?

I have nexus 4 and samsung galaxy s III and I would like to have the recent app and blink feed as on Sense 5 ROMs.

Is there any Sense 5 ROMs for those mobiles or is there anything that would make it possible to have these features on mentioned devices ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since HTC Sense is non-free software, using it on a non-HTC phone would be software piracy. The best you can hope for is a third-party app or ROM that aims to look similar.

Comment: Is there any sense ROMs for those devices ?

Answer (score 1):

Sense is made by HTC for HTC so no you can't put it on other phones. That said, I recently read an article that Blinkfeed and some of their other cooler closed source apps are going to be made available on the play store for other devices later this year. Looks like Blinkfeed specifically is already avaialable. Hope this helps.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.htc.launcher